# Open application with browser link

Tags: html, javafx, mime-types

We have a web application which is used to manage a list of main records in a database via a Spring Boot Web server talking to a back-end Java Server.

We also have a JavaFX standalone application which is used to graphically manipulate sub-records of these main web records, using a similar connection to the back-end Java Server.

We want to be able to launch this JavaFX application by clicking on a link next to each of the main records in the web interface. We would like to do this as seemlessly as possible.

At the moment the only way I can think that we can do this, is to use the Browser's 'Applications' set up to associate a particular MIME file type with the standalone JavaFX application, and somehow pass the UID of the record we click on as the 'file' being 'downloaded'.

Trouble is I'm not really sure what I should be googling for, to find out about this download process. For instance, does the browser pass the 'file' in a MIME message that is passed to the application, or does it save the 'file' in a temporary directory and then call the application with the temporary file path?

Has anyone done this sort of thing before, that could give us some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a turnkey solution but I think what you are looking for is a custom [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (like the [Magnet URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) `magnet:`, `mailto:`, or `tel:`).

Here is an article about [launching applications using custom browser protocols](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols) and here is [how to register an application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) on Windows.

You will have to modify the **Windows Registry** to link your custom protocol to an application, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```