# what is "steam://" is this a link? do other programs have this type of link?

Tags: windows, browser, registry, url-scheme

If I write on Google Chrome in the url bar steam:// or battlenet:// and I have installed these programs,and i press enter, these program will start , my question is, can I do the same thing with other programs? If so how? Where do I find their "links" , it's correct to call those "links"?

i don't know what are those things i call them "links" but i am not sure what are they, i am searching for more information about those "links" but i can't anything anywhere , please help me

(that's my first question here , i hope that's the corrct place to ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch an application from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136606/6869922)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open application with browser link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094336/open-application-with-browser-link)

Comment: i hope this answer your question [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27326527/15274960)